# Can I deep-freeze bread, rolls and other baking?

Tags: bread, frozen

Yesterday I hit a notice in my local mall saying (my own Polish->English translation):

> Bread, rolls and other baking made out of previously frozen raw-cake. Don't deep-freeze again!

Should I read and understand it literally?

For how long I reach past with my memory, both my mother and now my wife (for the entire period of our marriage) were purchasing more (sometimes way more) breads, rolls etc. than just for the current usage and they were deep-freezing obsolete part "for future usage".

I've been eating previously deep-frozen bread for years. Now, it seems I was doing something bad.

Comment: Hey, if you've been doing it for years, what information do you need from Seasoned Advice?  Seems like you already know the answer.

Comment: Is it possible that your translation is incorrect? I can see that re-freezing previously frozen bread etc might be a problem (mostly with drying out rather than food safety), but I don't think freezing bread baked from previously frozen raw dough would hurt, unless the bread etc you are buying is still raw dough and then you are attempting to re-freeze.

Comment: I agree with @bob1 It kinda sounds like its talking about repeated freezing and thawing... though I still don't know why that would merit a warning, I'd expect poor quality, not a lack of safety, from that kind of treatment.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I've been doing it for years, but only recently I was warned that I might be doing this all wrong. I wanted Seasoned Advice to confirm or reject my suspicions.

Comment: @bob1 & Megha Seems you're correct. Clearly translation mistake can be a problem here. Yes, I am talking about re-freezing or freezing for the first time a bread or roll made out of previously frozen raw dough. So, yes, it seems that this isn't a food safety problem (this is what I wanted be confirmed here or not), but then again, yes, the question remains what merit a company (quite large -- Carrefour) for issuing a warning (which in generally doesn't send out a marketing-positive message).

Comment: @trejder always trust your own tested experience over the opinions of a bunch of strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Could it be that the translation is indeed correct but it is the health and safety police, marketing or legal department going over the top? I have seen "Do not reheat" on everything from dried pasta to raw cubed beef recently. When the supermarkets concerned are contacted they don't seem to be able to answer why.

Comment: @FuzzyChef No, because I am just a mere consumer, and by no means -- a dietary, food or cooking specialist. So I reserve the right to have at least certain of my tested experiences to be totally wrong. BTW: If I'd totally trust all the tested experiences of my mother, I'd most likely be right now a dying fat guy, because she was always putting her so called experience over knowledge obtained from some books, articles, public discussions or any other source, other than herself. And she was cooking awfully fat and unheathy for the whole of her life.

Comment: I'd say that someone could craft a nice answer out of these comments (that re-freezing baked bread, rolls or cooing made out of previously frozen dough) most likely doesn't have a health-related issues and only cause bread etc. to get dried and only matter local supermarket's legal departments. I could then accept such answer to bring someone some rep.